# How to update attributes while doing a duplicate Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

We are creating a scheduling app and attempting to create a copy/paste function for schedules from week to week.  I am trying to figure out how to duplicate a schedule for certain period of time, while updating the attributes upon paste.  Right now I can copy the schedule, but when running it on postman, the dates and times stay the exact same (as we would expect with a .dup.)  I believe it would be best to set the start/end times to nil and then upon paste maybe the attributes get updated at that time?

Here is the function I have so far:

```
def copy
    set_calendar
    if params["start_date"] && params["end_date"]
       start_date = params["start_date"].to_date
       end_date = params["end_date"].to_date
        if @calendar.users.owners.include?(current_user) || @calendar.users.managers.include?(current_user)
            @past_shifts = Shift.where(calendar_id: @calendar.id, start_time: start_date.beginning_of_day .. end_date.end_of_day).to_a
            if
              @past_shifts.each do |past_shift|
                shift = past_shift.dup
                shift.users = past_shift.users
                shift.update(shift_params)
                shift.save
              end
             render json: "copied", status: :ok
            else
             render json: @usershift.errors, status: :uprocessable_entity
            end
        else
            render json: ("You do not have access to copy shifts"), status: :unauthorized
        end
    end
end
```

The shift.update(shift_params) is the part that needs to update the start and end times.  Here are the shift params:

```
def shift_params
    params.permit(:start_time, :end_time, :calendar_id, :capacity, :published)
end
```

As far as relationship set ups, this current method is being created in the shifts controller.  Shift has many users through usershifts, user has many shifts through usershifts, and usershift model belongs to both.

Comment: FYI `if @past_shifts.each` is not doing anything useful or correct. The result of `.each` is just the collection itself, so that `if` can never be `false`. Calling `.save` inside the `each` is also not safe, the `.save` method just returns `false` on failure, and you're silently ignoring the return value. You probably want a `.save!` which will raise an exception on failure.

Comment: Have a look at this gem which might help you achieve your end goal  https://github.com/amoeba-rb/amoeba

Comment: .save! outside of the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just curious - are you sure `params` for your `copy` method contains values for `start_time` and `end_time`? If so, why not to use them directly:

```
shift.start_time = params['start_time']
shift.end_time   = params['end_time']
```

With use `shift_params` you will also update other 3 attributes: `:calendar_id, :capacity, :published`. Not sure if this is necessary in this case.

Using `shift.update` method, in this case, is not reasonable. It works with existing record and saves updated attributes to the database. In your case the record is new, and you save all the changes with calling `shift.save` later.

Comment: I don't think your ```ActiveRecord``` object for ```Shift``` model has a ```new``` method. So it won't work at all. Please check the docs: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Comment: I guess I answered my own question, Shift.new resulted in undefined method undefined method `new' for #<Shift:0x00007fba82717bd8>

Comment: Shift.new worked as well, but it's again creating exact copies with same start and end times.  I want those fields to return nil or empty until pasted back in.